# Kinetics.js to automatically redraw canvas on user actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using Kinetics.js to operate with my canvas and jQuery to handle user actions. So all functions work perfectly fine, when I use them one by one. But when I try to combine two functions for one event like $('.selections img').click........(see below) The function just sets background and ignoring text. However, text layer is created, but for some reason I can't see it. I tried to change order of function calls with no luck.

When I check console, there are no mistakes or alerts, and when I use console.log to check my variables - all of them are printed to console.

What might be the problem here?

PS. the goal here is to hold img and t variables and use them to:
first - draw the background on canvas,
second  - print text over existing background on separate layer

```
 img = '';
 t = '';
 function setCanvas (){
        hiddenCanvas = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container : 'hiddenCanvasHolder',
        width : 2340,
        height : 1660

    });
}

function setBackground (image){
        background = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var imageObj = new Image();
     imageObj.onload = function (){
     var backImg = new Kinetic.Image({
         x: 0,
         y: 0,
         image: imageObj,
         width: 2340,
         height: 1660
         });
   background.add(backImg);
   hiddenCanvas.add(background);         
     };
     imageObj.src = image;
}

function setText(txt){
    textLayer = new Kinetic.Layer ();

    var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 200,
        y: 500,
        text: txt,
        fontSize: 70,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fill: '#555',
        align: 'center'
        });
    textLayer.add(text);
    hiddenCanvas.add(textLayer);
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
setCanvas();
setBackground(img);
setText(t);
/* Handles image selection and background setting for canvas */
$('.selections img').click(function(e) {
    img = $(this).attr('alt');
    textLayer.destroy();
    background.destroy();
    setBackground(img);
    setText(t);
});

/* Handles text input field and text printing to canvas */
$('#print').click(function(e) {
    t = $('#quoteInput').val();
    background.destroy();
    setBackground(img);
    textLayer.destroy();
    setText(t);
});

/* Handles quote selection from database instead of input it manually */




});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have variables hidden inside function scope that are required in other functions.

- hiddenCanvas
- background
- textlayer
- img
- t

So,

- Set these vars as global or
- Pass them where needed or
- create them when needed

A better resource approach is to destroyChildren() in layers instead of destroying the layers themselves:

```
     background.destroyChildren();

    textLayer.destroyChildren();
```

Also, you’re storing the image path in the img’s alt property.

That’s disrespectful to disabled viewers who need that property to help them understand the image.

Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ZFz3z/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:234px;
  height:234px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var hiddenCanvas = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container : 'container',
        width : 234,
        height : 234
    });
    var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
    hiddenCanvas.add(background);
    var textLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    hiddenCanvas.add(textLayer);


    function setBackground (image){

         var imageObj = new Image();
         imageObj.onload = function (){
         var backImg = new Kinetic.Image({
             x: 0,
             y: 0,
             image: imageObj,
             width: 234,
             height: 234
             });
             background.destroyChildren();
             background.add(backImg);
             background.draw();
         };
         imageObj.src = image;
    }

    function setText(txt){
        var text = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: 20,
            y: 50,
            text: txt,
            fontSize: 36,
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            fill: '#555',
            align: 'center'
            });
            textLayer.destroyChildren();
            textLayer.add(text);
            textLayer.draw();
    }

    /* Handles image selection and background setting for canvas */
    $('.imgs').click(function(e) {
        img = $(this).attr('src');
        setBackground(img);
    });

    /* Handles text input field and text printing to canvas */
    $('#print').click(function(e) {
        t = $('#quoteInput').val();
        setText(t);
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="print">Text</button>
    <input id="quoteInput" type="text" value="Hello">
    <img class="imgs" src="houseicon.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, great answer. This works perfect. Thanks for your time and effort.   Muchos gracias amigo.